# Harvest Chosen multiselect dropdownlist inconsistently populates with set value

Tags: ajax, vb.net, jquery-chosen, harvest

I have a ASP.net webform populated with data from a MS SQL DB, and allows you to edit values.

The web app uses a Harvest Chosen multiselect dropdown list (max=1) to select two different persons picked from the same list of information, but on two separate controls.

When I refresh the page, sometimes both controls are populated with the correct value, sometimes neither or one are.  I tested in the console and it is definitely pulling the correct information from the DB, but I must be missing something relating to how these procedures are executed.  I have done this work with VB.NET and ASP controllers in the past.  This is my first time using AJAX and web method functions.  I believe I am missing an update somewhere, or not understanding the order in which code is executed.

I tried explicitly stating the order of operations in the .aspx page, and then doing no update triggers until after all the code for the controller had been executed, but this appears to have broken both controllers (the both end up looking like normal select controllers).  Apologies if my terminology is not on point, I am very self-taught.  The current state of the code where I get inconsistent application

The .aspx page is as such.  Each control has a set of different parameters that affect how it is populated, and what happens when it changes.

```
<select class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Assign a scientist" name="ChosenScientist" style="width:800px;" id="cmbChosenScientist">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        handleChosenControls("select#cmbChosenScientist.chosen-select");
    </script>
</select>
<select class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Assign a supervisor" name="ChosenSupervisor" style="width:800px;" id="cmbChosenSupervisor">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        handleChosenControls("select#cmbChosenSupervisor.chosen-select");
    </script>
</select>
```

The aspx page passes the controller name to a function which first defines all of the parameters used by the controllers.

```
function defineChosenControls(controller) {
    switch (controller) {
        case "select#cmbChosenScientist.chosen-select":
            currentData = JSON.stringify({ sqlQueryName: "studyScientist" + "/" + MainContent_txbStudy.value });
            populateData = JSON.stringify({ sqlQueryName: "userList" });
            changeData = JSON.stringify({ strControlName: controller, arrValues: JSON.stringify($(controller).val()), strArg1: MainContent_txbStudy.value });
            break;
        case "select#cmbChosenSupervisor.chosen-select":
            currentData = JSON.stringify({ sqlQueryName: "studySupervisor" + "/" + MainContent_txbStudy.value });
            populateData = JSON.stringify({ sqlQueryName: "userList" });
            changeData = JSON.stringify({ strControlName: controller, arrValues: JSON.stringify($(controller).val()), strArg1: MainContent_txbStudy.value });
            break;
    }
}
```

The function that handles the populating the options, setting the current value, and handling changes is as follows:

```
function handleChosenControls(controller) {
    //Purpose: Any time a Chosen control is loaded, changed, etc., this is run.
    defineChosenControls(controller);
    $(controller).chosen({ max_selected_options: 1 });

    //Script for populating the control
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ClientToServer.aspx/GetDT",
        data: populateData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            for (line of JSON.parse(response.d)) {
                $(controller).append('<option value="' + line[Object.keys(line)[0]] + '">' + line[Object.keys(line)[0]] + '</option>');
            }
            $(controller).trigger("chosen:updated");
        },
        error: function (response) { console.log("ERROR: Unable to pass changed values from controller " + controller + " to server-side."); }
    });

    //Script for determining current value during load
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ClientToServer.aspx/GetDT",
        data: currentData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            for (line of JSON.parse(response.d)) {
                $(controller).val(line[Object.keys(line)[0]]).trigger("liszt:updated");
                console.log(line[Object.keys(line)[0]]);
            }
            $(controller).trigger("chosen:updated");
        },
        error: function (response) { console.log("ERROR: Unable to retrieve current value of " + controller + " from server-side."); }
    });

    //Script for when a value in the control is changed
    $(controller).on('change', function (e) {
        defineChosenControls(controller);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ClientToServer.aspx/PassJqueryControlValue",
            data: changeData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (response) { console.log("ERROR: Unable to pass changed values from controller " + controller + " to server-side."); }
        });
    });
}
```

I expect both controls to have the proper value in the DB, and those values are being written in the browser console properly, but the harvest chosen controls are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to call the code after load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    handleChosenControls("select#cmbChosenScientist.chosen-select");
    handleChosenControls("select#cmbChosenSupervisor.chosen-select");
});
```